# Prevent unpoly to make browser history change

Tags: javascript, unpoly

I'm filling some parts of the page using unpoly on page start by the call to function:

```
up.compiler('a.auto-follow', function(link) {
  up.follow(link)
})
```

And it works fine but it changes the address line of the browser. In my case this is not needed. How can I stop unpoly from doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not found the way for this to work with up.follow but I found that in my case the function up.replace fits nicely. It replaces the fragment on the page with the fragment from the provided url and has option to not change the history of the browser. So, now my code looks like this:

```
<script>
var url = "/some/url"
up.replace(".some-class", url, {history: false});
</script>
```